# Nested generics in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have the following code:

```
function testFunc<T>(
    a: keyof T,
    b: keyof T
) {
    return function(object2: T): T {
        return object2;
    }
}

const obj2 = {
    a1: 1,
    b1: 2,
    c1: 3,
    e1: 4,
    d1: 5
}

const result = testFunc('a1', 'b1')(obj2);
const c1 = result.c1; // Error. Property 'c1' does not exist on type '{ a1: any; } & { b1: any; }'. It's wrong

// We can try this

const result2 = testFunc<typeof obj2>('a1', 'b1')(obj2);
const c12 = result2.c1; // Works great
```

How can a generic be used from a nested function without explicitly specifying the type in testFunc (*`testFunc<typeof obj2>`*) ? Thanks.
You can see here: https://tsplay.dev/mbk7BW

Comment: Yes, but if I add a generic parameter, the code still doesn't work the way I want

Comment: I'm afraid it's not clear what you're asking. You **seemed** to be asking how the code you've shown works, but I think you must be asking something else.

Comment: Have you considered reversing the currying (so that you pass object first, then the fields you want to handle)?

Comment: @raina77ow I would like it with this syntax :)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Updated the example, it may become clearer. I want to use generic type in first function from nested function

Comment: Given `"a1"` and `"b1"`, do you expect the compiler to figure out that T is `typeof obj2` on its own?

Comment: @jtbandes Yes, that's what I want

Comment: How should it know that T isn't `{a1: string, b1: number, z: null}`?

Comment: @jtbandes we pass the argument obj2, the compiler knows the type of obj2 and can take the type from it

Comment: I see. I don't think that's supported: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strict=true#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKygXigbwIYC4oDsCuAtnBAE4A0UcOBxZAvgNwBQzAZvrgMbACWA9rioZSAHgAqAPgAUAaxyyIIfmyjiAlDmkAPHBpSSoAN368AJumZRrUUhGD5SQ6euSS0TZvVYdufQVBs-Pw6OPAI6pY2wqTSAOQYceo66izerEA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm, type inference doesn't work that way in TypeScript.  As soon as you call `testFunc('a1', 'b1')`, the compiler has already specified the generic type parameter `T`; there's no way to defer that specification.  Put another way: the compiler cannot [contextually type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) the function returned from `testFunc('a1', 'b1')` based on the fact that you go on to pass `obj2` into it.  It's as if you wrote the following code:

```
const returnedFunction = testFunc('a1', 'b1');
/* const returnedFunction: (object2: { a1: any;} & { b1: any;}) => 
   { a1: any; } & { b1: any; } */

const result = returnedFunction(obj2);
/* const result: { a1: any; } & { b1: any; } */

const c1 = result.c1; // oops
```

The type of `returnedFunction` is a function whose input and output is of type `{a1: any} & {b1: any}`... and therefore `result` is of type `{a1: any} & {b1: any}` and the compiler knows nothing about its `c1` property.

---

In order to fix this, I'd recommend changing the type parameters so that `returnedFunction` still has enough information to do what you want:

```
function testFunc<K extends PropertyKey>(
    a: K,
    b: K
) {
    return function <T extends Record<K, any>>(object2: T): T {
        return object2;
    }
}
```

Here, `testFunc` is not generic in `T`, since `a` and `b` don't contain enough information to produce a very meaningful type for `T` (`{a: any} & {b: any}` is the best the compiler can do).  Instead we make it generic in `K`, the union of the key types of `a` and `b`.

And then, the returned function is itself generic in `T`, which is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to an object type with at least the keys in `K`, but possibly more.

Now when you call `testFunc('a1', 'b1')`, the result is more strongly typed:

```
const returnedFunction = testFunc('a1', 'b1');
/* const returnedFunction: 
   <T extends Record<"a1" | "b1", any>>(object2: T) => T */
```

And thus it does what you want when you pass `obj2` to it:

```
const result = returnedFunction(obj2);
/* const result: {
  a1: number;
  b1: number;
  c1: number;
  e1: number;
  d1: number;
} */

const c1 = result.c1; // okay, number
```

Now that it works when you save the intermediate result, you can stop doing that and it will still work:

```
const result = testFunc('a1', 'b1')(obj2);
const c1 = result.c1; // okay, number
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?&strict=true#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB5ATgSwOZIN4Ch8likAzAV2HgBcMB7YJa6agMUvgB4AVAPgAoiJYXQA2AEwAKaOjABcSANYQAnnVJJuAGiHDiwCAHdpshcrUbuupAEo814WgjVyaRhSq0GSfnQBGAFYQNABMCtw24fZ6MUhOLm5I-kGhANwOJAC+1tnW8AxQ1EmBIUgAvNGxIACMCtU6sUh+tUghDbHwLQDM7TEQLQAsvXriLQCsOYTC+cCFcc6uBuLsnvSMFcyFK-D8AOQ1u1pIu827NunCAPQAVEgzc-GLEMscXsAKvoHB1GF4SDUKEDAFSpTJIABkf2agOBoLsZV4SAyfwB-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)